# getting indices of factors of an np outer product given a value condition

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to get the the indices of factors for  outer products that has passedd a critera.

beginner here, tried googling and searching SO and tabbing the available np functions for something but did not find anything

## python 3.6

```
x= [2,3]
y= [4,5]

z  = np.multiply.outer(x, y)

array([[ 8, 10],
       [12, 15]])
```

## for example:

```
for i in z:
    for j in i:
       if j >= 10:
```

Then looking for something that will give (x0y1,x1y0,x1y1) in some form

Comment: `np.where(z>=10)`  or its transpose `np.argwhere`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you look for [`numpy.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

then you can write:

```
x_cords, y_cords = numpy.nonzero(z > 10)
```